# PHP execution time: How to measure using a symfony system

Tags: php, symfony, email, symfony-3.4

I am trying to send out a bigger amount of emails using PHP in a symfony 3.4 system. Now the script stops due to php time execution limit, which of course I need to work around.

My idea is to put all emails to sent in a table email_queue and then send them after they are saved in the queue.

So I am saving all these emails, displaying a page with a progress bar and making an ajax call which should send emails out up to under the time limit, report back how many it sent out (to update the progress bar) and if something is left in the queue, the scipt is called again till everything is sent.

So far so good. Now I try to measure the execution time of the ajax script part to stop sending before I reach the 30 seconds time limit.
Now for some reason the measurement is always much smaller then the 30 seconds, but before the measured execution time even reaches something like 2 seconds, the script stops due to reaching the time limit. Why is that so?
This is how I do my measurement:

```
    $executionTimes = [];
    $executionPoints = [];
    $timeStart = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'];
    foreach ($mailQueue as $mail) {

        // do some mail configuration

        // send the email

        $now = microtime(true);
        $executionTime = $now - $timeStart;
        $executionTimes[] = $executionTime;
        $executionPoints[] = $now;
        if ($executionTime >= 10) {
            break;
        }
    }
    // return data
```

Using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']` I thought I'd get the real execution time including all the symfony overhead. Is that not correct?

Here is the result of one run:

```
{
  "timeStart": 1525702394.248,
  "executionPoints": [
    1525702394.863065,
    1525702394.866609,
    1525702394.870812,
    1525702394.874702,
    1525702394.878718,
    1525702394.882434,
    1525702394.886418,
    1525702394.890428,
    1525702394.894365,
    1525702394.899119
  ],
  "executionTimes": [
    0.6150650978088379,
    0.6186091899871826,
    0.622812032699585,
    0.626702070236206,
    0.6307179927825928,
    0.6344339847564697,
    0.6384181976318359,
    0.6424281597137451,
    0.6463651657104492,
    0.6511189937591553
  ]
}
```

So the last execution measurement was under 0.7 seconds, but there the script execution stoped.

I did a lot of research already but I just can't figure out why my script is doing things it shouldn't. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For something like this, you shouldn't be doing it in the context of an HTTP request, especially if it's a lot of emails. You should use a message queue and run a separate command-line process that does the work of sending the emails - in that context, PHP can run for as long as necessary.

Comment: set_time_limit isnt a option ?

Comment: I agree with @MatthewDaly commentary, you should use a queue, especially to sending emails, it's a time expansive task. You could just query your `email_queue ` table in your AJAX calls to know how many emails left you have to send :)

Comment: If i increase set_time_limit, the progress bar would look very unresponsive ...

Comment: @MatthewDaly: So you would recommend having a cron job that looks at the queue from time to time and sends all emails that are in it, right?

Comment: @MathiasBader That would be one approach, but it's not what I was thinking. I would look for a queue implementation of some sort for Symfony (I use Laravel, which has its own queueing system included, but you should be able to find something for Symfony). There are a number of queues you can use, depending on library support, including Redis, RabbitMQ and Beanstalk.

Comment: @MathiasBader The idea is that your application pushes the data needed to send the email onto the queue. A separate PHP worker process is running constantly and that picks up each message and sends the email. Usually these can also handle trying again later if something goes wrong too.

Comment: I've sent tens of millions of emails from PHP, and while it can be done from web-browser, it's FAR easier from a command line script that would read/send/delete say ~50 emails, and exit, to then be restarted by a shell script or some other way.